# How to get result from regexp_match()

Tags: c++, regex

My code should do this:
input: (x+y) => (x*y) 
output: (x+y)
regexp works well I tested them on a website regexp101.com
If I remove the match parameter from regexp_match() code works.
But it does not return the regexp result.
I get this error when I run this command:

```
> g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp
```

ERROR

```
main.cpp:14:9: error: no matching function for call to 'regex_match'
    if (regex_match(formula,match, firstBrace)){
        ^~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/regex:6038:1: note: 
      candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter '_BidirectionalIterator'
      ('std::__1::basic_string<char>' vs. 'std::__1::match_results<const char *,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::sub_match<const char *> > >')
regex_match(_BidirectionalIterator __first, _BidirectionalIterator __last,
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/regex:6049:1: note: 
      candidate template ignored: could not match 'const _CharT *' against 'std::__1::string' (aka
      'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >')
regex_match(const _CharT* __str, match_results<const _CharT*, _Allocator>& __m,
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/regex:6059:1: note: 
      candidate template ignored: deduced type 'match_results<typename basic_string<char,
      char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >::const_iterator, [...]>' of 2nd parameter does not match
      adjusted type 'match_results<const char *, [...]>' of argument [with _ST =
      std::__1::char_traits<char>, _SA = std::__1::allocator<char>, _Allocator =
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::sub_match<const char *> >, _CharT = char, _Traits =
      std::__1::regex_traits<char>]
regex_match(const basic_string<_CharT, _ST, _SA>& __s,
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/regex:6080:1: note: 
      candidate template ignored: could not match 'const _CharT *' against 'std::__1::string' (aka
      'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >')
regex_match(const _CharT* __str, const basic_regex<_CharT, _Traits>& __e,
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/regex:6089:1: note: 
      candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_regex' against 'match_results'
regex_match(const basic_string<_CharT, _ST, _SA>& __s,
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/regex:5366:5: note: 
      candidate function template not viable: requires at least 4 arguments, but 3 were provided
    regex_match(_Bp, _Bp, match_results<_Bp, _Ap>&, const basic_regex<_Cp, _Tp>&,
    ^
1 error generated.
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string formula;

    cout << "Write down a formula" << endl;
    cin >> formula;
    cmatch match;

    regex firstBrace("(\\()(\\w\\+)+(.\\))\\s?");
    if (regex_match(formula,match, firstBrace)){
        cout << "String 'a' matches regular expression 'b' \n";
        cmatch mcopy (match);  // copy constructor
        for (unsigned i=0; i<mcopy.size(); ++i)
            cout << "match " << i << ": " << mcopy[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

How can I get the result from regexp?

Comment: formula is `string`, so use `smatch` instead of `cmatch`. `s` - string, `c` - char.

Comment: another issue, I hope you are aware that `cin >> ..` reads until first whitespace. Better is to use `getline(cin,formula)`.

Comment: @rafix07 works, I did as you had told me, btw thx for the explanation I didn't know it, post an answer I'll mark as correct answer

Comment: @rafix07 Do not answer in the comments section. Answer in the answer section. Is it confusing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code doesn't compile because type of target doesn't match to type of *match* results. If you pass `string` as input, matched results will be stored in `smatch`. When input is `const char*`, results are stored in `cmatch`.

You have to replace `cmatch` occurences by `smatch`.